# How to insert or delete rows in individually locked cells in excel 2016?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In my excel list I locked some cells. And want to able insert or delete rows.
[image: lock with this options]
Rows and column by name "Total"  contain formulas. when I insert a row and add values into cells, cells in "Total" row work well, but  cells in "Total" column don't calculate and could not delete newly inserted row.
[image: could not delete row and H4 cell is not calculated]

Please help me
I want to protect colored cells, able to add or remove rows, that formulas works correctly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserted rows inherit cell properties from the row above, but not the formulas.

After inserting the row, you need to unlock the sheet and copy the formulas into the new cells. You can do this by-hand or using VBA e.g.

```
''1. Unlock Sheet.
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"
''2. Copy row above.
''3. Select the row that was inserted below.
''4. PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
''5. Re-lock Sheet.
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="YourPassword", _
  DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
  AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
```

You could then define your table as a TableObject in Excel (using the Insert tab), and then use the Worksheet_TableUpdate event to trigger the routine above.

Some References:

- [Worksheet.Protect Method (MSN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx)
- [Worksheet.TableUpdate Event (MSN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229788.aspx)